# Capturing Last Timestamp from a column in Talend

Tags: talend

In the talend pipeline below table_old and table_new draw data from same source table with different date ranges and different defined context. I have a requirement to having lastupdated (which is max of timestamp column)) column as new column added to the existing table. I have used a separate tpostgresqlinput to calculate max(timestamp) and using tmap i am adding that. I am using (select max(timestamp) from root_table). In local its working good when i am deploying it to higher environments, due different context, i am getting multiple lastupdated timestamp. Can anyone identify the design flaws here. I want that once the max(timestamp) is calculated only that value is inserted in the final table for all set context i.e. entire lastupdated column should have single timestamp. Can this be achieved by any different approach?. Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image: design]

Comment: did you try using a tAggregateRow component and then use the Max() function ?  after tmap drag that component use a group by and in functions use max in your wanted field

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to define the value of the date in a previous subJob and then use that value in the subsequent subJob the easiest way to do this is to define a context parameter and use the tContextLoad component.

subjob1

tDBinput ===> tContextLoad (https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/8.0/context/tcontextload)

SubJob 2 as normal except inside the tMap remove the lookup flow and simply use context.date as the expression.